# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at coldfusion.filter.FormScope.parseQueryString(FormScope.java:355)

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, jrun

we suddenly started receiving the below errors from ColdFusion 8:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: ROOT CAUSE: 
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   coldfusion.filter.FormScope.parseQueryString(FormScope.java:355)  at
>   coldfusion.filter.FormScope.parsePostData(FormScope.java:327)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.FormScope.fillForm(FormScope.java:277)  at
>   coldfusion.filter.FusionContext.SymTab_initForRequest(FusionContext.java:438)
>     at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:33)    at
>   coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
>     at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:198)   at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
>     at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)   at
>   com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doHttpServletRequest(FusionReactorCoreFilter.java:503)
>     at
>   com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doFusionRequest(FusionReactorCoreFilter.java:337)
>     at
>   com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorCoreFilter.java:246)
>     at
>   com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorFilter.java:121)
>     at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)   at
>   coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
>     at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>     at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)   at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)    at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)   at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)    at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
>     at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
>
> at
>   coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:70)
>     at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>     at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)   at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)    at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)   at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)    at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
>     at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)

I compared to coldfusion configuration of a working server and there is nothing noticeable.

Our default-web.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <!--FusionReactor filter - created Mon Oct 08 12:12:10 CEST 2012-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>FusionReactor</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>D:/FusionReactor/instance/coldfusion.cfmx8.SRVWWEBT05/conf/reactor.conf</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>FusionReactor</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <display-name>Default Web Application Settings</display-name>
    <description>Settings </description>
    <!--
 <filter>
   <filter-name>JRunTimingFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>jrun.servlet.filters.TimingFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>JRunTimingFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jrun.servlet.file.FileServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>browseDirs</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletInvoker</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JSPServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jrun.jsp.JSPServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>keepGenerated</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>translationDisabled</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cacheTags</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JSTServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jrun.jsp.JSTServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JspLicenseServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.license.JspLicenseServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>use-servlet-security</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JRunStatistics</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/jrunx/instrument/Results.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JspLicenseServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JSTServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jst</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletInvoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JRunStatistics</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/JRunStatistics</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!--
 <error-page>
    <exception-type>jrun.jsp.compiler.JSPCompiler$CompoundCompilerException</exception-type>
    <location>/jrun/jsp/error-pages/CompoundCompilerException.jsp</location>
 </error-page>

 <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
    <location>/jrun/servlet/error-pages/ServletException.jsp</location>
 </error-page>

 <error-page>
    <exception-type>jrun.jsp.parser.TokenMgrError</exception-type>
    <location>/jrun/servlet/error-pages/ServletException.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
-->
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.io.FileNotFoundException</exception-type>
        <location>/jrun/servlet/error-pages/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

do someone has a hint on this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to an .Net Http module that was filtering out every requests on the server and modifying them.